# How to make ascending axis on plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am just a beginner matlibplot
I try to make a plot which will have ascending axis. In the picture below, you can see that values are strangely spread (I believe as a plot reading it from file).

[image: here is a plot]

Comment: I found that a format is wrong - i send a table of values with ' ' and that is a problem. Anyone know solution ?

Comment: It would be incredibly helpful if you provided code and what you've already tried to accomplish this. Check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)